# How can I run an ANY CPU .NET executable programmatically in either 32-bit or 64-bit configurations?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# application that is built to run on both 32-bit and 64-bit processors. I am attempting to enumerate the modules of all processes on a given system and this becomes problematic when trying to enumerate 32-bit process modules from a 64-bit application; Windows or .NET prohibits it.

I thought it would be pretty cool if I could re-launch the application from within itself, but force it to run as 32-bit, and then it would correctly enumerate the process modules it missed on the last run.

How can I run an executable programmatically and indicate that even though it was built with an `ANY CPU` configuration, it should run as a 32-bit process?

The code below throws a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` with the text "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsWow64Process(
     [In] IntPtr hProcess,
     [Out] out bool lpSystemInfo);

private static void Main()
{
  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("ProcessModulesDump.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
  {
      using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
      {
          using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(gzipStream))
          {
              foreach (Process process in processes)
              {
                  writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", process.Id, process.ProcessName);

                  //bool lpSystemInfo;
                  //if ((Environment.Is64BitProcess && 
                         IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out lpSystemInfo)) ||
                         (!Environment.Is64BitProcess &&
                          !IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out lpSystemInfo)))
                  //{
                      foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
                      {
                          writer.WriteLine("\t{0} - {1} ({2})", 
                              module.BaseAddress, 
                              module.ModuleName, 
                              module.FileName);
                      }
                  //}
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to enumerate the processes, and tell us the exact wording of the error message you are receiving.

Comment: Can you work around the problem by launching a 32-bit helper executable that loads and runs your real executable as if it were a library?

Comment: @hvd Indeed I could. I wanted to avoid having two executables and thought it would be neat if you could set some kind of option on the process when starting it to indicate it should be forced to run as 32-bit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have added the code which grabs the processes and dumps the modules. I also commented out the code which would allow the process to be run as either 32-bit and 64-bit and still function normally, in order to show that the code breaks in this case. I added the exception type and message as well.

Comment: There's a better way to detect if you are running as 64bit...which is safe no matter if your running on a 32bit or 64bit version of Windows....here.. http://1code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39074#842775

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it your problem is with issuing the `IsWow64Process` call when it's not available/not appropriate....try doing your detection with this code:

- http://1code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39074#842775

When you get past that, you could then explore ways to be able to list the modules of 32bit and 64bit processes in a platform agnostic way:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/11/10/491647.aspx

Use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to query the required information...see the 3rd post down that mentions `UseWMIToGetProcesses`().

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/491ea0b3-3e5b-4fa2-a2c3-2f1e485aed0c/enumerate-both-32bit-and-64bit-managed-processes

Use `EnumProcessModulesEx` (supported in Vista onwards...when you detect you are in 64bit mode) as it can enumerate the 32bit and 64bit process list (see very end of this link):

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e1323f9-986d-4abe-b545-ef04be5aaf58/how-do-i-enumerate-all-modules-of-a-wow64-process
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682633%28VS.85%29.aspx

Use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to enumerate the Processes (you have to be careful in defining the structs):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/SI7TY8Kb65E

Comment: My answer (since deleted) was basically your first point, WMI is only useful for processes but not their modules.

Answer (score 3):

According to Rick Byer's article, [AnyCPU Exes are usually more trouble than they're worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/8/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx), the decision on the "bitness" used to launch AnyCPU applications is determined by the OS loader and you don't have any say in the matter.

Specifically:

> AnyCPU EXEs are a little more complicated since the OS loader needs to
>   decide how to initialze the process. On 64-bit OSes they are run as
>   64-bit processes (unless the 'ldr64' master OS switch says otherwise),
>   and on 32-bit OSes they are run as 32-bit processes.

So, it looks like your best option is to create and launch a second, 32-bit exe and launch that.

Comment: One approach is to move your code into a separate class library assembly (keep it AnyCPU) - then create two applications (one x86, one x64) and have them both call the class library to do the work. The .exe causes your process to then run in the required "bitness", and the class library is JIT compiled as it is run to suit the flavour that the .exe needs.